# Extract date from string Pandas data frame

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have this column Date_X in pandas dataframe which is a object. I am not able to use pandas to_datetime function here. I want to convert this column to a range of 1 to 365, using which I can carry on my analysis.

```
29JAN14:21:16:00
01FEB14:00:11:00
30JAN14:15:11:00
01FEB14:00:07:00
29JAN14:19:31:00
30JAN14:23:52:00
29JAN14:19:18:00
30JAN14:16:46:00
30JAN14:21:39:00
31JAN14:17:40:00
01FEB14:00:16:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) by providing the format explicitly using the `format` keyword argument. Example -

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(dataframe['column'],format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S')
```

The explanation for the format -

> `%d` - 2 digit date
>   `%b` - 2 letter month abbreviation
>   `%y` - 2 digit year
>   `%H` - 2 digit hour (24-hour format)
>   `%M` - Minutes
>   `%S` - Seconds

Demo -

```
In [46]: pd.to_datetime('29JAN14:21:16:00') #Not working
Out[46]: '29JAN14:21:16:00'

In [48]: pd.to_datetime('29JAN14:21:16:00',format='%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S') #Working
Out[48]: Timestamp('2014-01-29 21:16:00')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was working on it for 3 hrs. Greatly relieved :)

Comment: Glad I could be helpful :-)